# Cant make css pure parallax fit with rest of the page

Tags: html, css, parallax

So I basically have the exact same code as [this](https://codepen.io/samdbeckham/pen/OPXPNp) code pen i found (with different images but same css and html), but what im not being able to do is add the rest of my page under that parallax effect
I have a normal page with the following structure:

```
<section class="position-relative bg-blah-blah">
<divs>
</divs>
</section>
.
.
.
<section class="position-relative bg-blah-blah">
<divs>
</divs>
</section>
```

So where should i put the rest of my page after that parallax code so that the parallax hides under my first section and the rest of the pag follows

Im sorry if this is not the correct way to make a question, its my first time

Answer (score 0):

with the same CSS you can't put the flow of the page right behind it because the CSS is aligned to display absolute. So it doesn't matter where you put your own code the first 2000px will disappear behind the cover. You could start to adjust the CSS and change from display absolute to display relative e.g. the class "parallax". But your problem here is not the HTML flow but the CSS.

Comment: Thank you
So now i changed the .parallax and the .parallax--cover to position relative and instead of the current div with class .parallax--cover I placed my first section with same class in its place, and it works better, the parallax goes behind my first section and the rest of the sections follow, but the thing is between the parallax and the first section there is a separate scroll (so basically I can scroll the parallax and the first section apart from the rest of the page which I dont want)  Its probably the overflow-y attribute but i cant make it work another way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).